# Crystal Reports Code 128 Barcode Printing Shape Instead of Number

Tags: crystal-reports, code128

I have a formula field with a font of Code 128, to print string input from a user.

It prints fine every time except when two (2) zeros are next to each other. But the thing is its fine when it prints 100, but say I do 1000, it prints some rectangle shape in the barcode. Again 1001 it prints fine, 10001 it prints with a rectangle.

Here is the formula field:

**@QuantityBarCode**

```
' http://support.wisys.com/documentation/Crystal_Report_IDAutomation_Basic_Syntax_Barcode_Settings.htm

Dim DataToEncode As String
DataToEncode = Trim({@Quantity}) ' Quantity
Dim PrintableString As String
Dim DataToFormat As String
Dim WeightedTotal As Number
Dim CurrentValue As Number
Dim CheckDigitValue As Number
Dim C128CheckDigit As String
Dim StringLength As Number
Dim I As Number
Dim CurrentCharNum As Number
Dim CurrentEncoding As String
Dim C128Start As String
Dim CorrectFNC As Number
Dim CurrentChar As String
CorrectFNC = 0
PrintableString = ""
DataToFormat = DataToEncode
DataToEncode = ""

'Here we select character set A, B or C for the START character
StringLength = Len(DataToFormat)
CurrentCharNum = Asc(Mid(DataToFormat, 1, 1))
If CurrentCharNum < 32 Then C128Start = Chr(203)
If CurrentCharNum > 31 And CurrentCharNum < 127 Then C128Start = Chr(204)
If ((StringLength > 4) And IsNumeric(Mid(DataToFormat, 1, 4))) Then C128Start = Chr(205)

'202 & 212-215 is for the FNC1, with this Start C is mandatory
If CurrentCharNum = 202 Then C128Start = Chr(205)
If CurrentCharNum = 212 Then C128Start = Chr(205)
If CurrentCharNum = 213 Then C128Start = Chr(205)
If CurrentCharNum = 214 Then C128Start = Chr(205)
If CurrentCharNum = 215 Then C128Start = Chr(205)
If C128Start = Chr(203) Then CurrentEncoding = "A"
If C128Start = Chr(204) Then CurrentEncoding = "B"
If C128Start = Chr(205) Then CurrentEncoding = "C"

For I = 1 To StringLength
    'check for FNC1 in any set which is ASCII 202 and ASCII 212-215
    CurrentCharNum = Asc(Mid(DataToFormat, I, 1))
If ((CurrentCharNum = 202) Or (CurrentCharNum = 212) Or (CurrentCharNum = 213) Or (CurrentCharNum = 214) Or (CurrentCharNum = 215)) Then
        DataToEncode = DataToEncode & Chr(202)
    'check for switching to character set C
ElseIf ((I < StringLength - 2) And (IsNumeric(Mid(DataToFormat, I, 1))) And (IsNumeric(Mid(DataToFormat, I + 1, 1))) And (IsNumeric(Mid(DataToFormat, I, 4)))) Or ((I < StringLength) And (IsNumeric(Mid(DataToFormat, I, 1))) And (IsNumeric(Mid(DataToFormat, I + 1, 1))) And (CurrentEncoding = "C")) Then
    'switch to set C if not already in it
        If CurrentEncoding <> "C" Then DataToEncode = DataToEncode & Chr(199)
        CurrentEncoding = "C"
        CurrentChar = Mid(DataToFormat, I, 2)
        CurrentValue = Val(CurrentChar)
    'set the CurrentValue to the number of String CurrentChar
If (CurrentValue < 95 And CurrentValue > 0) Then DataToEncode = DataToEncode &                                                                                          Chr(CurrentValue + 32)
        If CurrentValue > 94 Then DataToEncode = DataToEncode & Chr(CurrentValue + 100)
        If CurrentValue = 0 Then DataToEncode = DataToEncode & Chr(194)
        I = I + 1
    'check for switching to character set A
ElseIf (I <= StringLength) And ((Asc(Mid(DataToFormat, I, 1)) < 31) Or  ((CurrentEncoding = "A") And (Asc(Mid(DataToFormat, I, 1)) > 32 And (Asc(Mid(DataToFormat, I, 1))) < 96))) Then
    'switch to set A if not already in it
        If CurrentEncoding <> "A" Then DataToEncode = DataToEncode & Chr(201)
        CurrentEncoding = "A"
    'Get the ASCII value of the next character
        CurrentCharNum = Asc(Mid(DataToFormat, I, 1))
        If CurrentCharNum = 32 Then
            DataToEncode = DataToEncode & Chr(194)
        ElseIf CurrentCharNum < 32 Then
            DataToEncode = DataToEncode & Chr(CurrentCharNum + 96)
        ElseIf CurrentCharNum > 32 Then
            DataToEncode = DataToEncode & Chr(CurrentCharNum)
        End If
    'check for switching to character set B
 ElseIf (I <= StringLength) And (((Asc(Mid(DataToFormat, I, 1))) > 31) And ((Asc(Mid(DataToFormat, I, 1)))) < 127) Then
    'switch to set B if not already in it
        If CurrentEncoding <> "B" Then DataToEncode = DataToEncode & Chr(200)
        CurrentEncoding = "B"
    'Get the ASCII value of the next character
        CurrentCharNum = Asc(Mid(DataToFormat, I, 1))
        If CurrentCharNum = 32 Then
            DataToEncode = DataToEncode & Chr(194)
        Else
            DataToEncode = DataToEncode & Chr(CurrentCharNum)
        End If
    End If
Next I

'<<<< Calculate Modulo 103 Check Digit >>>>
WeightedTotal = Asc(C128Start) - 100
StringLength = Len(DataToEncode)
For I = 1 To StringLength
    CurrentCharNum = Asc(Mid(DataToEncode, I, 1))
    If CurrentCharNum < 135 Then CurrentValue = CurrentCharNum - 32
    If CurrentCharNum > 134 Then CurrentValue = CurrentCharNum - 100
    If CurrentCharNum = 194 Then CurrentValue = 0
    CurrentValue = CurrentValue * I
    WeightedTotal = WeightedTotal + CurrentValue
    If CurrentCharNum = 32 Then CurrentCharNum = 194
    PrintableString = PrintableString & Chr(CurrentCharNum)
Next I
CheckDigitValue = (WeightedTotal Mod 103)
If CheckDigitValue < 95 And CheckDigitValue > 0 Then C128CheckDigit = Chr(CheckDigitValue + 32)
If CheckDigitValue > 94 Then C128CheckDigit = Chr(CheckDigitValue + 100)
If CheckDigitValue = 0 Then C128CheckDigit = Chr(194)
DataToEncode = ""

' Final Barcode format
Formula = C128Start & PrintableString & C128CheckDigit & Chr(206) & " "
```

The image shows 1000 as text (user input) and the barcode prints with the rectangle and I also added the barcode text to the bottom right corner to show what the barcode text looks like when encoded. I have noticed that the asterisk seems to be in the text when I get this weird shape.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: If you create a new formula, supply `10001` as the value, set its font to the bar code font, what happens?  Do you still get the same issue?

Comment: If your talking about just taking the quantity user input (@Quantity) with no encoding and just applying the Code 128 bar code font, it prints out fine with no weird shape, but it is not scannable. It needs to be encoded with the start/stop characters and checkdigit.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions? I can't figure this out.

Comment: Wanted to give my resolution to fix this.

I was using a "code128.ttf" font file. I was provided with a "IDAutomationC128M.ttf", used this as my new font for the bar codes on the label and everything works great. Prints and scans correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I know that probably it is too late, but I am answering this question for future if someone will have similar issue.

This code is provided for IDAutomationC128M.ttf font which have character on ascii 194 and font Code128.ttf does not have it... on ascii 194. The same character in Code128.ttf is available on ascii 207.

To make this code working with Code128.ttf just change **chr(194)** to **chr(207)**, e.g.

There is:

```
DataToEncode = DataToEncode & Chr(194)
```

Should be:

```
DataToEncode = DataToEncode & Chr(207)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code above and Mateusz solution but it is not entirely correct.

In order to effectively correct the code provided and create some readable barcodes when 0s are next to each other, you need to change **chr(194)** to **chr(32)** everywhere you see it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the Crystal Report function of BarCode128A for the free Code128 font**

```
  Function (StringVar input)
    NumberVar CheckDigit := 0;
    NumberVar i := 0;
    StringVar BarCodeOutput := "";
    StringVar BarCodeInput := input;
    StringVar BarCodeTemp := "";
    NumberVar SingleByte := 0;
    BarCodeInput := Uppercase(input);
    For i := 1 To Len(BarCodeInput) Step 1 Do
        (SingleByte := Asc(Mid(BarCodeInput, i,1));
            If SingleByte >=0 And SingleByte < 32 Then
                BarCodeTemp := BarCodeTemp + Chr(SingleByte +64)    
            Else if SingleByte > 31 And SingleByte < 127 Then
                BarCodeTemp := BarCodeTemp + Chr(SingleByte - 32)       
            Else
                BarCodeTemp := BarCodeTemp + ""
        );

    For i := 1 To Len(BarCodeTemp) Step 1 Do
        (SingleByte := Asc(Mid(BarCodeTemp, i,1));
            CheckDigit := (CheckDigit + (SingleByte * i)) Mod 103;
        );
    BarCodeTemp := BarCodeTemp + Chr(CheckDigit);

    For i := 1 To Len(BarCodeTemp) Step 1 Do
        (SingleByte := Asc(Mid(BarCodeTemp, i, 1));
            If SingleByte =0 Then
                BarCodeOutput := Chr(206)       
            Else if SingleByte > 0 And SingleByte < 94 Then
                BarCodeOutput := BarCodeOutput + Chr(SingleByte + 32)
            Else
                BarCodeOutput := BarCodeOutput + Chr(SingleByte + 103)
        );

    Chr(203) + BarCodeOutput + Chr(206)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code @Astriti. I haven't messed with this stuff in years!! lol